# How to access AWS SQS from websphere liberty using JNDI

Tags: jndi, amazon-sqs, websphere-liberty

In our project we have websphere liberty server and IBM MQ as message server. We are moving in cloud. We want to replace IBM MQ with AWS SQS. In server.xml we have following entries to get IBM MQ connection factory using jndi.

```
 <jmsQueueConnectionFactory connectionManagerRef="ABCConnMgr" jndiName="jms/ABC_QCF">
        <properties.wmqJms channel="CH.ABC.SVRCONN" hostName="abc-mq1-st4.ebiz.abc.com" port="21414" queueManager="ABC401" transportType="CLIENT"/>
    </jmsQueueConnectionFactory>
    <connectionManager agedTimeout="-1s" connectionTimeout="180s" id="ABCConnMgr" maxIdleTime="1800s" maxPoolSize="50" minPoolSize="0" purgePolicy="EntirePool" purgeagedTimeout="-1s" reapTime="180s"/>

<jmsQueue id="ABC.ORDERMGT.INPUT.QA" jndiName="jms/ABC_ORDERMGT_INPUT">
        <properties.wmqJms baseQueueName="ABC.ORDERMGT.INPUT.QA"/>
    </jmsQueue>
```

Similarly I am looking jndi configuration for Amazon SQS connection factory and sqs queue. I think IBM need to develop resource adapter for SQS and provide this configuration.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, you will need a resource adapter for Amazon SQS.  It could be provided by any third-party vendor, does not need to be IBM for it to work because JCA is a standard.

Once you have a resource adapter, here are some helpful Knowledge Center links to get it configured in Liberty,

[Overview of JCA/JMS config](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=resourceadapter-overview-jca-configuration-elements)

[Configuring Resource Adapters](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=elements-configuring-resource-adapters)

[Configuring JMS Connection Factories](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=elements-configuring-jms-connection-factories)

[Configuring JMS Destinations](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/was-liberty/nd?topic=elements-configuring-jms-destinations)